# MySQL. Как объединить строки по ID?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Помогите пожалуйста, я новичок в SQL.

Есть две таблицы, YC_records и YC_services, структура такая:

YC_records

[image: YC_records]

YC_services

[image: YC_services]

Я делаю вот такой запрос:

```html
SELECT COUNT(`YC_records`.`id`) FROM `YC_records` 
LEFT JOIN `YC_services` ON `YC_records`.`id`=`YC_services`.`record_id` 
WHERE `YC_services`.`title` NOT LIKE "" and `YC_services`.`title` NOT LIKE '%Отраб%' 
and `YC_records`.`create_date` BETWEEN "2022-12-01" and "2023-02-01" 
and `YC_records`.`company_id`=292435;
```

На выходе я получаю большее кол-во записей, чем на самом деле. Это связано с тем, что к одной записи (YC_records.id) может быть привязано несколько услуг (YC_services.id), и при объединении происходит дубликация записей. Как мне доработать запрос так, чтобы на выходе записи (YC_records.id) объединялись по ID?

Результат запроса с SELECT * для наглядности. Мне надо чтобы сначала прошла фильтрация по title, а потом уже объединилось всё по ID, значение title неважно после фильтрации

[image: Результат запроса с SELECT *]

Comment: Запрос не соответствует результату - он выбирает одно поле, а на скрине их дофига. *Как мне доработать запрос так, чтобы на выходе записи (YC_records.id) объединялись по ID?* допустим, объединились.,. какое из двух разных значений поля, скажем, `title`, должно попасть в эту единственную запись и почему?

Comment: Абсолютно не важно, так как оно уже пройдет фильтрацию по title, а от запроса мне нужно только кол-во записей

Comment: На скрине с результатом я заменил SELECT COUNT(`YC_records`.`id`)  на SELECT *

Comment: Чтобы наглядно показать что происходит

Comment: Прочитайте [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Особенно пункты 5 и 3. Поправьте вопрос. И не надо скриншотов. [Почему в вопросе не следует выкладывать скриншоты кода/данных/ошибок?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, добавив DISTINCT в COUNT

```html
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`YC_records`.`id`)) 
FROM `YC_records` 
LEFT JOIN `YC_services` 
ON `YC_records`.`id`=`YC_services`.`record_id` 
WHERE `YC_services`.`title` NOT LIKE "" and `YC_services`.`title` NOT LIKE "%Отраб%" 
and `YC_records`.`create_date` BETWEEN "2022-12-01" and "2023-02-01" 
and `YC_records`.`company_id`=292435;
```